# Close window automatically after printing dialog closes chrome

Tags: javascript, printing, window

[image]

I need a solution to close the window after print in javascript.
I have tried the below but the window closes even if doing nothing.

```javascript
    setTimeout(function () 
    {
     window.print(); }, 500);
    }
    window.onfocus = function () 
    {
      setTimeout(function () 
      {
          window.close();
      }, 500); 
    }
```

please help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close the window after the printing, you could use [onafterprint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint)

```
window.onafterprint = function(event) { window.close() };
```

Note that the **onafterprint** event is raised after the user prints, or if they abort the print dialog.

**==UPDATE==**

For the code mentioned, instead of directly giving "*thePopup.print*" you can call it using an anonymous function as a parameter for your loadingcompleted method.

```
addloadingCompleted(function() {
  thePopup.focus();
  thePopup.print();
  thePopup.close();
});
```

This is should *ideally* work for your case, however as I am not sure of what your loading method does and I hope it executes whatever is passed as its parameter, once the document loads.

Comment: I tried this but window closes even before print. Using chrome version 78+.

Comment: Can you please share your working code via https://jsfiddle.net/ to check further?

Comment: Sorry I don't have copy access in client's RDP. this is the code
Please refer attached image in the question.

Comment: I have updated my answer to this case. Let me know if it solves your problem!

Comment: No luck , window closes even before print. seems like version issue ? chrome.

Comment: It should not be a version issue, btw you mean to say that the window closes before the print is triggered? What does your adLoadingCompleted() method do?

Answer (score 0):

You could use like bellow

```
var printElement = document.getElementById(elementName);
var newWin = window.open('');
if (newWin) {
 newWin.document.write(createYourHtmlHere);
 newWin.print();
 newWin.close();
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to print the pdf from array buffer ..when I tried this with Html got a blank page print preview. Used embed and iframe tags.